# Getting sheet name dynamically with fixed indirect cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created an Excel file named `Sales` consisting of the sheets: 
 `Settings`, `Country A`, `Country B`.

In the sheet `Settings` I have the following values:

```
          A                 B                      C
1
2       $B$1
3       
4       Country A
5       Country B
6
```

In the cells `A4` and `A5` I have the following formulas:

```
A4 = MID(CELL("filename",'Country A'!$B$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",'Country A'!$B$1))+1,255)
A5 = MID(CELL("filename",'Country B'!$B$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",'Country B'!$B$1))+1,255)
```

As you can see I use the formula as a `dynamic reference` to get the name of the `other sheets` into the sheet `Settings`.

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I want to achieve that the part `$B$1` within in the formula is used as an `Indirect` reference to the `Cell $A$2` within in the sheet `Settings`. At the same time I want that the `sheet name` remains dynamically.

Therefore, the desired result is that the `sheet name` is automatically adjusted if the user changes the name of the sheet but in case the user delets columns, rows or cells the reference always remains at `$B$1`.

What do I need to change in my formula to make this work?

Comment: Tricky... I think it can't be done. You will always end up with a circular reference.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the desired outcome is. Can you clarify? What should end up in Settings!A4? (Or is that not the target cell?)

Comment: I would assume you need one live link to the sheet from which you would extract the name string. If one cell in the sheet Settings is ='Country A'!A1 and you link another one with the formula =FORMULATEXT() to it you will get a string that changes dynamically when the sheet is renamed. This string can then be easily manipulated to match whatever you want in your INDIRECT function.